# Is there a way to migrate JPA table names with Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have JPA table annotations and I would like to change some table names to follow a specific naming convention. The problem is that those tables are already in production. I don't like the idea of manually creating a new table and inserting the data because I have no idea how to deal with id's and associations.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Edit: I am using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update.

Comment: rename the tables using `alter table`, then edit or re-generate your Entity classes

Comment: Use an SQL-script with `alter table` statement to rename the tables.

Comment: I am using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update so tables are created automatically. I think the SessionFactory will create a new table before I get to do the alter table query.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a migration production script that does an:

   RENAME TABLE ....
2. You modify the entity table mappings to match the new table names
3. You do a production update that does both 1) and 2)

Comment: I would like to make the migration at the start of my application and not manually. The problem is that I have automated schema update (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update) which will create a new table before I get to rename the table. Maybe I should get rid of it but that's another story.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong. You should have never relied on hbm2ddl=auto for production systems. You can create the scripts from HBM as your initial scripts and add incremental update ones later. Use [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) to automatically run those incremental scripts.

Comment: I'm considering to refactor the codebase to use initial table creation scripts. It hasn't been my decision to use the hbm2ddl=auto but it can be my decision to get rid of it. I have to check out that Flyway. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are welcome. For what it's worth, I once had to maintain a hbm2ddl=auto like system and every production migration was simply a pain. Not to mention individual branches diffs and such. Incremental update scripts is so much better, and you can benefit from DB custom DDL support, beyond Hibernate powers.